# SQL takes longer to load results only some times on second computer

Tags: c#, sql, networking

i have a main server with my SQL database and another client PC which connects to that server database using the connection string in my application mentioned below(i am using Ethernet cable connected to a switch to connect this ), strange thing is on the client PC it takes 0.02 seconds to load my results which consists of estimated 10000 rows but that too only some of the times not always normally it loads in 0.00 seconds. i have installed SQL server on client PC also to test and run query directly from the SQL studio to see if there is any mistakes in my C# application but still its the same results in SQL studio 0.02 seconds. i would like it to load in 0.00 seconds always, is any possible fix on this? below is my connection string which connects to database

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ABRARAHMED-PC\ABRAR;" + "Initial Catalog=abrarTest;" + "User id=abrar;" + "Password=*****;";
```

i have also changed the connection string to use IP address instead of name but still i found the same results.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean SQL Server database? SQL is a language, supported by many different products.

Comment: you would need to profile it, get out the sql profiler, it also depends how its connecting, the machines maybe connecting differently. btw thats not a query, thats just the connection string.

Comment: @BugFinder apologies i am still learning can you please explain how to profile it?

Comment: If you are using the same query it's possible that on subsequent requests your DBMS is returning cached results...

Comment: @mark i also thought about it i read it last night, but how do i stop this?

Comment: @Abrar you don't want to stop any caching - it's useful optimisation.  I personally think that 0.02 seconds is reasonable for a database request.  But to reduce the time you have certain options - reduce the size of the result set for example, or optimise your indexes.  But why do you think 0.02 seconds is too long for your request ?

Comment: @Mark my application requires user to always open a stock file to find products, i would not mind the 0.02 seconds at all but why only some times it does this and other times its 0.00

Comment: @Abrar Don't worry about the difference - it happens on modern DBMSs that are constantly trying to optimise their behaviour.  But are you loading your entire stock file into your client application ?

Comment: @Mark yes i am data binding to a dataGrid, it has about 5 columns 10000 rows

Comment: @Abrar there is a profile tool as part of sql, take a look on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the first time you query a SQL database, it has to retrieve the table from the hard disk, put it into memory, and then work out which rows you wanted.

Retrieving data from the hard disk takes time. The disk has to move the read head to the right place, and then wait for the disk to rotate past it. It's quick, but not instant. 20ms is faster than you can blink - it's pretty fast for a mechanical device.

Database engines attempt to avoid this delay by caching data. They guess that you might want the same data again, so they leave it in memory for a while in case you ask the same data straight away. That's why it's much quicker the second time.

You're probably wondering how to keep all your data in memory all the time, but generally the hard disk is about 1000 times bigger than the memory, so it won't fit. Generally the disk is full of information that is only used occasionally, and the database will cache the information your user needs a lot, and performance will be acceptable.